# Matlab - how to draw tangent on curve

Tags: matlab

I have plotted a graph in matlab with:

```
plot(x,y)
```

and my graph has different slopes, how do i draw tangents on each slope and calculate the coefficient for the slope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have an explicit function for the plotted points, you can use [finite differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) for estimating the derivative. The following is appropriate for points not on the border of the data span:

```
plot(x,y);
hold all;

% first sort the points, so x is monotonically rising
[x, sortidx] = sort(x);
y = y(sortidx);

% this is the x point for which you want to compute the slope
xslope = (x(1)+x(end))/2;

idx_a = find(x<xslope,1,'last');
idx_b = find(x>xslope,1,'first');
% or even simpler:
idx_b = idx_a+1;
% this assumes min(x)<xslope<max(x)

xa = x(idx_a);
xb = x(idx_b);
slope = (y(idx_b) - y(idx_a))/(xb - xa);
```

Now drawing that slope, it depends on what you want: just a short line:

```
yslope = interp1(x,y,xslope);
ya_sloped = yslope + (xa-xslope)*slope;
yb_sloped = yslope + (xb-xslope)*slope;
line([xa;xb],[ya_sloped;yb_sloped]);
```

or a longer line

```
yslope = interp1(x,y,xslope);
xa = xa + 4*(xa-xslope);
xb = xb + 4*(xb-xslope);
ya_sloped = yslope + (xa-xslope)*slope;
yb_sloped = yslope + (xb-xslope)*slope;
line([xa;xb],[ya_sloped;yb_sloped]);
```

I'm pretty sure there're no bugs in this code, but I'll test it out when I have matlab around ;)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to figure out the slope at whatever points you're interested in using (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) and then use plot() to draw a straight line that has that slope. To draw the line, you need the y intercept, and since you know the coordinates of at least one point on that line (which is the point you want to draw the tangent to), you can solve for b in the equation y=mx+b.

Comment: I counter repped this answer back up to 0.  It's not the best answer and it gives no insight into matlab code, but it's conceptually sound so I don't think it deserves a -1

Comment: I agree with this approach but I would add that depending on the horizontal resolution of your graph (how many points you have to plot), you might want to consider interpolating first to get a more accurate result. See interp() in matlab, it's quite simple.