# Draw tangent line on parametric curve with MatLab

Tags: matlab

The question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563931/matlab-code-to-draw-a-tangent-to-a-curve?lq=1) but here I have parametric equations such as:

x = sin(t)

y = cos(t)

How can I draw a tangent line on parametric curve at a particular point (the point is chosen by the user)?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a trivial problem of calculus to compute the tangent line, so if that is your question, it is off topic, belonging on a math site. If you know the line, then plot will plot the line. So what is your question?

Comment: @woodchips my question is how can I extend the code on referred link to parametric equations? clear?

Comment: Again, my answer is calculus. Can you take a derivative?

Comment: @woodchips I'm sorry for you. If you don't have ability to answer my question, why you report that as unclear???

Comment: Sorry, but I do know the answer to your question. It is simply time for you to open your calculus book, not plead for others to do your thinking for you on basic problems that are not really programming problems anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer rips the code from Rody Oldenhuis's nice one (which you link to). It only modifies the plotting routine to keep the selected point and tangent line attached to the circle. The rest, as the commentators point out, is just geometry:

```
function test

hh = figure(1); clf, hold on
grid on

x = [0:0.01:2*pi]';
f = @(x) sin(x);
g = @(x) cos(x);
fprime = @(x,y) -x./y;
circle = [f(x) g(x)];

plot(g(x), f(x), 'r')
axis tight

D = [];
L = [];
set(hh, ...
    'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @mouseMove,...
    'WindowButtonDownFcn', @mouseClick);


    function mouseMove(varargin)

        coords = get(gca, 'currentpoint');
        xC = coords(1,1);
        yC = coords(1,2);

        % find nearest point on the circle
        [minr2 imin]=min(sum((circle - ones(size(circle,1),1)*coords(1,1:2)).^2,2));


        if ishandle(D)
            delete(D);
        end
        D = plot(circle(imin,1), circle(imin,2), 'ko');

    end

    function mouseClick(obj, varargin)

        switch get(obj, 'selectiontype')

            % actions for left mouse button
            case 'normal'

                coords = get(gca, 'currentpoint');
                xC = coords(1,1);
                yC = coords(1,2);

                % find nearest point on the circle
                [minr2 imin]=min(sum((circle - ones(size(circle,1),1)*coords(1,1:2)).^2,2));

                xC=circle(imin,1);
                yC=circle(imin,2);

                m  = fprime(xC,yC);
                b  = yC-m*xC;

                if ishandle(L)
                    delete(L);
                end

                L = line(xC+[-pi/2;pi/2], m*(xC+[-pi/2;pi/2])+b);

            case 'alt'
                % actions for right mouse button

            case 'extend'
                % actions for middle mouse button

            case 'open'
                % actions for double click

            otherwise
                % actions for some other X-mouse-whatever button

        end

    end

end
```